# I want to disappear from windows network

Tags: networking, samba

By this I mean to not come up as (LINUX-PC) when a windows user opens network neighbourhood.
Unplugging is not an option, as I am running a multiplayer server every now and then, which we connect to via IP address.
Is there something in samba config etc that I can change to not advertise my linux pc while still having an IP address assigned?

Comment: Do you need Samba at all?

Comment: ok so you simply remove samba and install nfs support on windows ?

Comment: There no link between the fact that you have an IP address and that you run Samba. The purpose of Samba is to allow Linux to take part into Windows networks. Do you need to share files with Windows PC ? If no, remove Samba.

Comment: Can I disable samba without removing it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can disable samba without removing it

First stop samba

```
sudo service smbd stop
```

Stop NetBIOS

```
sudo service nmbd stop
```

then remove it from startup

```
sudo update-rc.d -f smbd remove
sudo update-rc.d -f nmbd remove
```

Service and config not removed from PC and you can start it when you need it with

```
sudo service smbd start
sudo service nmbd start
```